# Looking for an open-source C++ library which can fit a multivariate polynomial function to points in 3D space

Tags: c++, math, regression-analysis

I have been unsuccessfully looking for a C++ library that can approximate a polynomial function f(x,y) = z given a bunch of known points (x,y,z) in 3D space.

This is trivial to do using the fit function or curve-fitting tool in matlab (see image in link for a specific example), but I need to integrate this functionality into some existing software which is written in C/C++ hence why I'm specifically looking for a C++ library. Can anyone point me towards something that might work?

I have come across many curve fitting libraries, but they all seem to be limited to fitting 1D curves. I have been looking for regression and interpolation functions, perhaps I am looking for the wrong thing?

[image: Curve fitting in matlab example]

Answer (score 1):

Would a C library be acceptable?

[cminpack](https://devernay.github.io/cminpack/) is a good Levenberg-Marquardt implementation, which is a state-of-the-art curve fitting method, which also works for nonlinear problems.

Your problem is linear in its parameters and can be solved by [multivariate linear least squares methods available in GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/lls.html#multi-parameter-regression). You will need to:

- Translate your coordinate vectors into a multi-column `X` matrix containing columns for `x`, `x²`, `y`, `y²`, and so on for every known observation
- If your `z` values are stored in a matrix, unfold it into a vector containing `N*M` values

Once it has been done, feed the predictor matrix and the regressor vector to `gsl_multifit_linear`, and you'll get the polynomial coefficients.

If you do need to solve nonlinear problems, [GSL has a nonlinear least squares solver too](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/nls.html).